# Excel Compare Columns

Tags: excel, formulas

I have 2 columns, one with 2800 records and another with 20,001 records.

I am looking to find out if any of column I (2800 records) are listed in column BB (20,000 records), if it does = TRUE, if it doesn't = FALSE.

I tried the formula below and was given False even though I made one of the values for sure match.

=IF(I4=BB1:BB20001,TRUE,FALSE)

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: what are the data types of your columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in J4 on the 2,800 record set and drag down

```
=IF(COUNTIF(BB$1:BB$20001,I4)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```